# Displaying large dataset from SQL Server in ASPxPivotGrid with XPODataSource

Tags: sql-server, datagridview, devexpress, datasource

I have 300.000++ rows of data with XPODataSource. When I use direct query it take just 3 seconds (in SQL Server Management Studio), but when data displayed via ASPxPivotGrid, it takes one minute to load, it also take same amount of time when I do some action to this component (move column, sort data).

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: Don't display 300'000 rows at once .... rearchitect your solution! This cannot ever be fast and zippy....

Comment: Have a look at [LinqInstantFeedbackSource](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#CoreLibraries/clsDevExpressDataLinqLinqInstantFeedbackSourcetopic)

Comment: @marc_s, the grid doesn't show all rows, but it need all rows to process at runtime.